# Need help with Zend_db update

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Currently I'm working with Zend framework and I need help with Zend_db update in Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class.

Here is my SQL statement

```
UPDATE user
   SET password = '$password',
`enter code here`  WHERE email = '$email'
```

Here is my code in zend_db

```
   public function updatePassword($password,$email)
    {
       $data = array(
            'password' => $password
        );

       $where = "email = '". $email ."'";
    $this->update($data, 'email = '.$email);


    }
```

This only work if I update using int id as my where clause but I wanted to use a email string as a where clause.

Can someone please help me the best way to achieve this?

I wanted to be secure and avoid SQL Injection attack

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach only works with integer values, because the way you concat the where string does not escape the value. So if you do

```
'email = '.$email
```

It will product an sql string like this if you use the string "hello world"

```
WHERE email = hello world
```

This is an invalid SQL statement so the update does not happen. What you want to produce is a where clause like this

```
WHERE email = 'hello world'
```

There are multiple ways to do this, but the safest way to do that via Zend Framework is described in the [reference manual under "Example #24 Updating Rows Using an Array of Arrays"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html).

```
$data = array(
  'password' => $password
);
$where['email = ?'] = $email;
$this->update($data, $where);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code might help you :

```
 public function updateDetails($data, $emailId) 
 {
    $where = array('email = ?' => $emailId);
    $this->update($data, $where);
 }
```

Please let me know if you still face the problem.....?